# ANOVA for solar cell study

Tags: regression, anova, modeling

My friend is conducting a study on solar cells. The results obtained were the current (ampere), voltage (V), and resistance (ohms). Then, there were three dyes that were used: Dye 1, Dye 2, and Dye 3, and we recorded three trials for each dye. What statistical method should she use for comparative study?